# read basicauthentication use javascript

Tags: javascript, basic-authentication

I want to read basic authentication use JavaScript

[image]

We can read cookie or user-agent to use `document.cookie` and `navigator.userAgent` but i want read (Authorization: Basic).

Comment: thanks i see this and test this answer is not my question i want read Authorization:basic